# Developing an app that sends a picture to a web page using couchbase

Tags: database, server, couchbase

ok guys, im pretty confused with a class project i've been assigned. I need to make an app that allows the user to take a picture, and then send it to a database. I also need to create a webpage where all the pictures taken with the app will be shown. so, the user takes the picture with the app, and then it sends it to the page, where its displayed. I guess is something like a pseudo-instagram.

the part that really confuses me is the database/server part of the app. i think the app will send the pictures to the database, from where the website will retrieve the latest ones (or some other sorted way). after reading a little about databases i found couchbase and i think thats the way to go.

The part i dont really understand about couchbase is where is the data stored. does couchbase just gives me the database and i have to store all the information (photos) somewhere like a computer that acts as a server or in the cloud; or its stored in some kind of server provided by couchbase?

also, is what i described the way to go in this app? the basic idea is to send information from the app to a database/server and then retrieve that data to the webpage. any advice is truly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

couchbase provides key value store. Data is stored within the couchbase. In your case you need to store the images as value. CouchBase is capable of storing binary data. So, you probably want to convert your images in the binary data and store it.
CouchBase has great API, which you can query to retrive your images.
Not sure if this helps you. good luck with your project.